# A combinatorial problem about poker card and elastic band

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a poker card and an elastic band. The band is wound around that poker card. We are looking for different type of way to wound around card when all stripes are horizontal on backside.

Here is an example of three horizontal stripes on back which only two cases: (red lines are stripes on back, blue lines are stripes on front)[image: The examples of three horizontal stripes on back]

If two wound pattern are same after one rotate 180 degree we define they are same pattern.

How many different pattern are there if we have 7 horizontal lines on back.

Here is my attempt, we firstly forget that we need to consider the same patter situation.

Assume we have 4 horizontal line, as below:

[image]

Clearly $v_1$ has $4-1=3$ choices,$v_2$ has $4-2=2$ choices, and $v_3,v_4$ both has $1$ choice. Therefore we have totally 6 cases(if we don't get rid of same pattern).

So for 7 horiztonal stripes we have 6!=720 cases if we don't get rid of same pattern.

It would be great if someone could check my attempt. Could anyone give suggestion how to get rid of the same patterns?

Comment: To clarify, the two patterns you've shown are not considered the same as each other, right? But both of them are the same as their 180° rotations. If you can count the patterns that are equal to their rotations then you can determine exactly how much your original approach overcounts.

Comment: @Karl Thank you for this hint! I figure it out!

Comment: Nice! I'm curious how you counted the patterns that are equal to their rotations, since I didn't have a way to do that in mind.

Comment: @Karl I post my solution below, again thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Karl's hint. My solution is more tedious than I thought.

We firstly forget the restriction that two pattern are same if one is other's $180$ degree rotation.

When we have 7 horizontal stripes on back, the total count can be divided into two disjoint cases:

$$\underline{Case 1}. \text{those pattern similar to its self 180 rotation.}$$

$$\underline{Case 2}. \text{those pattern are not self similar.}$$

We already know without the restriction of similar pattern the total count is $6!=720$, now we need to find how many overcount we have.
Noted for every pattern in case 2, each pattern get counted twice. Because if we pick one pattern in case 2 and rotate it 180 degree, it must be one of 720 pattern and it can't in case 1 since it is not self similar.
So we can conclude we overcount the case 2 twice.

We first count the case 1: imaging you have two vertical line of 7 vertices here. On left denote them as $v_1,v_2,..,v_7$, on right denote them as $u_1,u_2,...,u_7$.

To count case 1, we need to divide case 1 into 3 subcases:

$\underline{Case 1.1}$: $u_1$ adjacent to $v_4$, if so then $u_4$ must adjacent to $v_7$,

[image]

consider the logest path $v_7u_7u_4v_4u_1v_1$, $v_1$ can only adjacent to 4 vertices: $u_2,u_3,u_5,u_6$($u_7$ can't be its neighbor otherwise we break the bond). Assume $v_1$ adjacent to $u_5$ then neighbor of $v_7$ is $u_3$. $v_5$ has only 2 possible neighbor and once we find the neighbor of $v_5$ we find the neighbor  of $v_3$.
$$\text{We have }4*2=8\text{ count }$$

$\underline{Case 1.2}$: $u_1$ adjacent to $v_7$

[image]

We still consider the longest path $u_7v_7u_1v_1$, note $v_1$ can't adjacent to $u_4$(if so $v_4$ must adjacent to $u_7$ and we again break the bond). So $v_1$ has 4 possible neighbor and WLOG let $v_1$ adjacent to $u_5$ then $v_5$ has only two possible neighbor. So still
$$\text{we have }4*2=8\text{ count. }$$

$\underline{Case 1.3}$: $u_1$ not adjacent to $v_4$ and not adjacent to $v_7$. Clearly $u_1$ has only 4 choices, let its neighbor be $v_5$ and hence $v_7$ has neighbor $u_3$. Still consider the endpoint of longest path $u_5v_5u_1v_1$ the neighbor of $v_1$ can only be $u_2,u_4,u_6,u_7$ let it be $u_5$ and we looking for neighbor of $v_3$ which can only be $u_2,u_6$.

$$\text{we have }4*4*2=32\text{ count. }$$
[image]

Sum up all those three subcases we get 48 number of case 1. So case 2 has 672 count and we overcount case 2 twice so we subtract 672/2=336.
$$\text{we have }720-336=384\text{ count. }$$